# How to render edge only object in Blender Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, wireframe

I was making a 3D model of Vibri from Vib-Ribbon and I was trying to get it as accurate by making it from edges only like the models in the original game, and I did it properly, but now I have to do the rendering part so I used Freestyle but it wouldn't show up for some reason.

It's empty:
[image: it's empty]

I found a question that I thought would be good but only worked on Blender 2.7.

I need help because I think it would be a waste of time to make a 3D model with rigging and everything just to not be able to make a test video to show my friends.

Preferably, I would not want it to involve modifiers because I want it to be as accurate as possible.

A screenshot of the thing in the viewport:
[image: a screenshot of the thing in the viewport]

This is more or less what I wanted to make it look like in the render:
[image: reference]

Comment: Blender will only show mesh faces in render. Curves and armature bones as well as meshes only containing vertices and edges without faces will be invisible.

Comment: is it possible to get them to show up or do I have to make a specific render engine or something

Comment: I decided to try writing a shader for it so if I eventually figure it out I'll put the code as an answer. It's now a Cycles-based question but that's better than figuring it out in Eevee.

Comment: Nevermind that was a horrible idea because I know nothing about writing shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the proper way would be to use something like *Grease Pencil* with a `Line Art` modifier—you might wanna look into that—but I'd like to showcase a method I use often: rendering viewport directly, *WYSIWYG* (what you see is what you get) style.

To get a look like your example, I'm following these steps below:

- Go to *Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport* and change the **Wire** color, which controls the color of your edges, to pure white
- Under *Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Theme Space > Gradient Colors* switch the **Background Type** to *Single Color* and make the gradient color pure black.
- In the 3D Viewport, make sure you're in *Solid View* mode. Open its options panel and switch the **Background** mode to *Theme* so it uses your theme settings you've just set

[image]

So, now your 3D Viewport is black, and your edges are white (you might wanna save that theme for later use). To not see faces, but only edges, you have a couple of options. You can simply enter into Edit Mode with your objects selected, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>X > Only Faces</kbd> to delete all faces. You can keep that procedural with [a very simple Geometry Nodes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyFFY.png). Another option is to use the *Wireframe* mode instead of *Solid*, but [that results in slightly dimmed whites for your edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI8Nz.png) and you can't pick and choose which objects get to be rendered as wireframe as you can in *Solid*.

That's about it. Blender has an option to render exactly what you see in the viewport called **Viewport Render Image/Animation** but it's not located in the *Render* menu, it's under *View* instead. It'll respect the settings in your *Output Properties* panel and if you're looking through a camera, it'll render what that camera sees:

[image]

Comment: it worked perfectly